# Facebook game with open graph error: "Requires extended permission: publish_actions"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a Facebook game and am attempting to publish open graph stuff.  My open graph specs have been confirmed by FB.  However, I still get error #200:

```
Requires extended permission: publish_actions
```

I've looked at all the previous Stack Overflow comments and can confirm that:

```
- my app is a game
- I have "Enhanced Auth Dialog" turned on
- I have "publish_actions" listed as one of the permissions I want
- I have the Action, the Object, and the Aggregation with sample data
```

However, a call to "/me/permissions" gives:

```
email: 1
installed: 1
(no publish_actions)
```

My preview log in dialog contains "This app may post on your behalf, including games you played and more." but actually authenticating with my test account doesn't show that message.

Anyone know what might solve this?

Comment: Would you show how you ask those permissions?

Comment: In my game's settings, I ask for their email address and also publish_actions. Is that what you mean, @AlexanderNenkov?

Comment: You should ask those permissions in the code

Comment: Says here that the permissions should be displayed in the initial auth dialog, if things are working right: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/

Comment: You still have to trigger that auth dialog yourself.

Comment: No, I don't think I should trigger it myself because people already see the auth dialog when they agree to play my game. They're already seeing and agreeing to the auth dialog, which contains email address, it just doesn't contain publish_actions for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add `publish_actions` to the `scope` for your auth dialog **after** you authed to this app with your account? If yes, try reauthing maybe. Check in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) if permissions are as they should for this app for this your current account.

To ensure that user has needed permission for something, you should **handle revoked permissions** - even if there would be no such situation like the one you described, and a user would simply allow all needed permissions, he can always remove this permission in the app's settings on FB. You can check [this FB blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/576/) and this [technical FB guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/handling-revoked-permissions/) for reference, or dig more if needed. This should handle your situation, I think.

**EDIT:**

I assume, of course, that you **have added** `publish_actions` to your `scope`, like that in JavaScript FB SDK (it's just an example, I don't know if you're using client or server side auth):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,publish_actions,etc...'});
```