# Facebook App - Prompt permission to post

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an app. It does not prompt users to Post on Wall permission, after the GO to App popup. I have given the following settings for my app in developer account.

```
User & Friend Permissions: email,user_activities,user_likes,publish_actions
Extended Permissions: publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access
```

When i click a "Preview Login Dialog" link, it shown the following rights in "GO to App" popup.

```
THIS APP WILL RECEIVE:

    Your basic info
    Your email address
    Your activities
    Your likes
```

But, when i access the app at the first time, it shown the following rights alone.

```
THIS APP WILL RECEIVE:

    Your basic info
```

Due to this, i could not post on well. I have checked.

Similarly, i have checked user's app setting page.
User account has no option like the below.

```
* Post on your behalf
* Access posts in your news feeds
```

What is wrong? I spent more than 3 hours to find out.

Comment: Please include the code that is invoking the login dialog.

Comment: Thanks. No need to login. Once you have logged in fb, you can access this app. So, we can't check scope while the user login. We have to set that options in developer apps setting page. I forget the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you have expected permissions set in the `scope` parameter of method invoking the login dialog:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_activities,user_likes,publish_actions,etc...'});
```

And just in case, to be sure that you will have needed permissions before doing something that needs them, try handling revoked premissions, as I pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619403/facebook-game-with-open-graph-error-requires-extended-permission-publish-acti/14762389#14762389).

BTW, be sure to request only permissions your app really needs. You can scare users with so many permissions. ;)

Comment: Thanks. No need to check the scope in login. Once you have logged in fb, you can access this app. So, we can't check scope while the user login. We have to set that options in developer apps setting page. I forget the settings.

Comment: Authentication goes to login process. so i have tried it. Great!!